# error on wordpress index page

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, indexing

I made a wordpress theme myself and now I want to upload it without "wordpress" in the link: (example.com/wordpress/home) so it should be a normal link. I followed a tutorial to reach this. The whole site is visible in the correct way, but only the index page gives an error.

For example (index page not working):
http://protoformat.nl/

(working page):
http://protoformat.nl/home

The tutorial I followed is in Dutch, but I will add it to this post too:
http://wpsitebouw.nl/wordpress-verplaatsen-van-map-naar-hoofdmap/#

Who can help me with making the index page visible without an error? I already took out 'wordpress' from the link.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You need to make sure

Go to Administration > Settings > Reading panel.

1. Set 'Front page displays:' to 'a static page' and choose the page you created 
   (your homepage) as the 'Front page.' If your WordPress site will contain a blog section, set 'Posts page' to the page you created for the blog. Otherwise, leave this blank.
2. Save changes.
3. Enable "Permalinks" to show the "page title" in the address.

Comment: Thanks! I changed front page to static page and choose my homepage.